# .net core 7 AddProblemDetails only show Response Header

Tags: error-handling, asp.net-core-webapi, middleware, response-headers, asp.net-core-7.0

I am using `AddProblemDetails`.

If I set my environment to `Development`, Swagger return error details in the response body, but if I set it to something else other than `Development`, it only show response headers.

Does anyone know how to config it to always show error details in the response body?

My `Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, config) => config.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration));
builder.Services.AddCustomCors()
                .AddAuthSupport(builder.Configuration)
                .AddCustomJson()
                .AddHttpClient()
                .AddProblemDetails();

builder.Services.AddDatabase(builder.Configuration)
                .AddCustomFluentValidation()
                .AddOpenAPISupport();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors()
       .UseFullSwaggerUI()
       .UseHttpsRedirection()
       .UseAuthentication()
       .UseAuthorization();

app.MapEndpoints();

app.Run();
```

This is my Production environment:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnbII.png)

This is the Development environment:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyQrh.png)

I tried to find any special setting in all config files but nothing special.

Comment: Not sure, which special settings you been tired, can you share that as well? so you are trying to bind response body other than development mode?